# jquery Jcrop how to do a round selection? Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, jcrop

I'm creating an app that let's users take a picture and from that picture they have to make a selection to work with. This selection has to be a circle with specific dimensions.

I'm wondering how I should do this. I have a working jCrop selectbox that draws a new square image to canvas. Now I want to make a circle of that image.

I assume that to be very difficult with pure javascript or jQuery. So I looked for a way to adapt the selection box of [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) to be a circle, but I can't find a way to easily do that.

The goal is to create a real image to save on the device for further usage.

I want to ask you a direction on how I should do this. How would one create a round image from a selection? Can I use Jcrop for that or are there better solutions?

In the end the result should be a round image just like Google Plus profile pictures:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with CSS.

For the crop tool use

```
.jcrop-holder div {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

and to display the profile image as circle

```
.profile-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. It is still rectangle selection if you add this css.